# MS Access - Object from another form isn't recognized

Tags: ms-access

Our school project is to make a voting system in MS Access. So far this is what I've done:

```
Private Sub Command7_Click()
    Dim President1 As Integer
    Dim President2 As Integer

    President1 = 0
    President2 = 0

    If Frame0.Value = 1 Then
        DoCmd.Close
        DoCmd.OpenForm "RESULTS"
        President1 = President1 + 1
        Me.lblpresresults1.Caption = President1
        DoEvents
    Else
        DoCmd.Close
        DoCmd.OpenForm "RESULTS"
        President2 = President2 + 1
        Me.lblpresresults2.Caption = President2
        DoEvents
    End If
End Sub
```

There are two forms, voting1 and RESULTS
There are two voting options in form voting1. When clicking a button beneath the two options, it should add +1 to a counter. And the resulting number should appear in a textbox in the form RESULTS.

But whenever i run it, it says "method or data member not found". Can someone help point out where the code went wrong? Is there something missing? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The above code is the code in the aforementioned button

Comment: Aggregate data should not be saved, it should be calculated when needed. Each vote should be a record in table then use that raw data to calculate the total votes. On second thought, nothing can prevent user entering multiple votes so maybe irrelevant

Comment: Me. refers to the form code is behind. If you need to reference other form then use its name: `Forms!Results.lblpresresults1.Caption`

Answer (score 0):

debugging.

try commenting out all the suspect lines using ' at the start of the line.

un-comment one at a time to find out which one is breaking your system.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the form before opening the next, thus pulling the feet under your code. Try:

```
Private Sub Command7_Click()

    Dim President1 As Integer
    Dim President2 As Integer

    DoCmd.OpenForm "RESULTS"
    If Frame0.Value = 1 Then
        President1 = President1 + 1
        Forms!RESULTS!lblpresresults1.Caption = President1
    Else
        President2 = President2 + 1
        Forms!RESULTS!lblpresresults2.Caption = President2
    End If
    DoCmd.Close

End Sub
```

However, that will alway set the caption to "1", not adding anything. So perhaps:

```
Private Sub Command7_Click()

    Dim President As Label
    Dim Votes     As Long

    DoCmd.OpenForm "RESULTS"      
    If Frame0.Value = 1 Then
        Set President = Forms!RESULTS!lblpresresults1
    Else
        Set President = Forms!RESULTS!lblpresresults2
    End If
    Votes = Val(President.Caption) + 1
    President.Caption = CStr(Votes)

    DoCmd.Close

End Sub
```

That won't save the votes anywhere, but that - I guess - is the next task.